# How to tell quickly if a file is in a directory that is linked?

Tags: symlink, ln

When I am working inside an IPython notebook, I sometimes do `!pwd` and of course it will show the directory that I am working in.  But sometimes these files are inside a directory that is linked.

e.g.,  when I do `!pwd` I'll see `/a/b/c/`, and when  use the `find` command to actually find this file, I see that it is at `/a/d/e/file_name.ipynb`.

But when I follow the links, I see that `/a/b/c/ -> /a/d/e/`.  What is annoying about this, is that I don't know where along the path it is linked.  It could have been `/a/b/ -> /a/d/` or something.

When I find out where a file exists, how do I find out where along the path it is linked?

Thanks.